# Appstore release process for iOS and tvOS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, tvos13

I am planning to release my first iOS app in AppStore today. I have two questions
1) The app is already approved so if I release it then how soon will it be available in store for user to download & install?
2) if there are some issues with the app then I need to rollback. Is it easy to rollback and how soon app disappear from the store?

Answer (score 1):

Once apps are released to the store it can take up to 48hrs for them to be visible. (In some rare instances even longer, especially if it is the first app of the account)

There's no easy way to rollback an app. For that you should do extensive on device testing via TestFlight or similar. You can remove an app from sale, i.e. it is no longer possible to download it. You can then submit an app update and request an expedited review to get the fix faster to your customers and the app back online.